# Too many redirects in redirect 301

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to make a redirect 301 from an old ulr to a new url.

old url: `/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework`

new url: `http://www.demo31.com/blog/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework`

In .htaccess I make this redirect like this ...

```
RedirectMatch 301 /php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework   http://www.demo31.com/blog/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework
```

But I've got the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like both URI's are on the same host (`www.demo31.com`), so when you use `RedirectMatch`, the part of the URI that matches is part of the redirect. Example

If I go to:

```
http://www.demo31.com/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework
```

1. The URI is `/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework`
2. The `RedirectMatch` directive matches the URI, redirects to:

   ```
   http://www.demo31.com/blog/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework
   ```
3. new URI is `/blog/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework`
4. however, the `RedirectMatch` directive matches the URI **again** since it contaings `/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework`

Try changing `RedirectMatch` to just `Redirect`. Or if you only want that specific URI to redirect (as opposed to something like `/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework/some/other/stuff` also getting redirected, add a few delimiters:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework$   http://www.demo31.com/blog/php/zend-framework/captcha-codigo-anti-spam-zend-framework
```

(the `^` and `$`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in two cases I've got the same result: Two many redirections :(((

Comment: Hi!!! Everything is alright!!! I made a mistake changing an .htaccess file from another directory!!! If I make the changes like you have commented everything is alright!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^bad_url$ good_url [R=301,L]
```

Thx ! works for me